# Поиск файла который имеет спецсимвол, и применение к нему прав. UNIX

Tags: unix, экранирование

Есть файлы:

```
\\test
test\
te\\st
```

`find ~test/* -name '*\\*'` , находит все файлы с \ , далее добавляю 
`find ~test/* -name '*\\*' | xargs -i{} chmod 777 {}` , и получаю ошибку что таких файлов нет, потому-что в аргументы уже один \ .
Вообщем как правильно проэкранировать бэкслеш чтоб возможно было применять права через xargs ?

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вероятно, проще всего воспользоваться опцией `-exec` программы *find*:

```
$ find где -name '*\\*' -exec chmod a=rwx {} \;
```

- `'*\\*'` — под этот шаблон попадут все файлы/каталоги, содержащие **хотя бы один** символ `\` (дважды повторен он для экранирования самого себя)
- `a=rwx` — это человекочитаемый синоним числа `0777`, понимаемого программой *chmod* в качестве первого параметра
- `-exec программа опции-параметры {} другие-опции-параметры \;` — это синтаксис опции `-exec` программы *find*. при желании `\;` можно заменить на `';'`. главное, чтобы эта точка-с-запятой была экранирована и не воспринималась оболочкой как оператор, соединяющий две команды оболочки.

---

хотя, конечно, можно воспользоваться и программой *xargs*. только для того, чтобы исключить интерпретацию экранирования и тому подобного, надо через конвейер между *find* и *xargs* передавать список, разделённый нулевыми символами, а не символами перевода строки:

```
$ find -name '*\\*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' chmod a=rwx '{}'
```

- `-print0` — сформировать список, разделённый нулевыми символами
- `-0` — читать список, разделённый нулевыми символами